# Применение триггеров Xaml

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Как реализовать чтобы при выборе итема с ComboBox`a, определенный контрол стал неактивным с помощью триггеров? И посоветуйте, пожалуйста, источники которые можно почитать чтобы разобраться с триггерами(желательно с примерами).

```
         <ComboBox>
                <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">Ежедневно</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem  Content="Еженедельно">
                   <!--Если был выбран итем => EnableDaysOfWeek.IsEnabled = true;--> 
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Ежемесячно</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Однократно</ComboBoxItem>
         </ComboBox>
         <UniformGrid Name="EnableDaysOfWeek" Columns="7" IsEnabled="False">
                <CheckBox>Пн</CheckBox>
                <CheckBox>Вт</CheckBox>
                <CheckBox>Ср</CheckBox>
                <CheckBox>Чт</CheckBox>
                <CheckBox>Пт</CheckBox>
                <CheckBox>Сб</CheckBox>
                <CheckBox>Вс</CheckBox>
         </UniformGrid>
```

Comment: `<ComboboxItem IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, ElementName=EnableDaysOfWeek}" />`? Триггер тут не нужен по идее.

Comment: А почитать можно например [на MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#styling_triggers) (автоматический перевод, сорри).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вот как-то так, триггеры не понадобились

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="0">
    <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">Ежедневно</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem  Content="Еженедельно" Name="Weekly">
            <!--добавляем имя для привязки-->
    </ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Ежемесячно</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Однократно</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
<UniformGrid Name="EnableDaysOfWeek" Columns="7" Grid.Row="1" IsEnabled="{Binding IsSelected, ElementName=Weekly}">
    <!--Если был выбран нужный итем => EnableDaysOfWeek.IsEnabled = true;-->
    <CheckBox>Пн</CheckBox>
    <CheckBox>Вт</CheckBox>
    <CheckBox>Ср</CheckBox>
    <CheckBox>Чт</CheckBox>
    <CheckBox>Пт</CheckBox>
    <CheckBox>Сб</CheckBox>
    <CheckBox>Вс</CheckBox>
</UniformGrid>
```